# Unexplained Remote Connection Issues with Jdbc.getConnection()

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, connection, remote-access

Colleagues,

What could be the reason for the error in the function?

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://www.uplaunched.com:3306/uplaunc1_MailerBees',{user: 'uplaunc1_googlescript', password: 'xxxxxxxxx'});
```

The same parameters...
The connection via Navicat works fine, but the connection from the Google script does not work.

[image: connection via Navicat]

Hosting: [www.bluehost.com](http://www.bluehost.com)

Computer addresses and Google server addresses are whitelisted. Navicat works great!
What do you recommend to do?

Error:
[image: exeption]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the error / exception message you get.

Comment: As @O.Jones a message has said, more information of the error would be nice. Also is the database name `uplaunc1_MailerBees`? Did you make sure of that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the "crooked hands" of the hosting technical staff.
Not all Google server addresses have been whitelisted.
The solution to the problem is here:

https://tastyplacement.com/how-to-connect-google-datastudio-to-mysql-database-cpanel-flavor